# 'npm start' does not work anymore

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

My npm start does not work anymore, but I still worked with it yesterday. I also haven't changed anything, as far as I'm concerned. I'm using it to start up my react starter kit (facebooks official starterkit). What could it be?

```
> apicalltestapp@0.1.0 start /Users/.../reactapp
> react-scripts start

module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'cross-spawn'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/reactapp/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node" "/Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! apicalltestapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the apicalltestapp@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the apicalltestapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs apicalltestapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls apicalltestapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/dswork/Coding/reactcafe/npm-debug.log
```

here is the npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.8
3 info using node@v6.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle apicalltestapp@0.1.0~prestart: apicalltestapp@0.1.0
6 silly lifecycle apicalltestapp@0.1.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle apicalltestapp@0.1.0~start: apicalltestapp@0.1.0
8 verbose lifecycle apicalltestapp@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle apicalltestapp@0.1.0~start: PATH: /Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/dswork/Coding/reactcafe/node_modules/.bin:/Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
10 verbose lifecycle apicalltestapp@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/dswork/Coding/reactcafe
11 silly lifecycle apicalltestapp@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
12 silly lifecycle apicalltestapp@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle apicalltestapp@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: apicalltestapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid apicalltestapp@0.1.0
16 verbose cwd /Users/dswork/Coding/reactcafe
17 error Darwin 15.6.0
18 error argv "/Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node" "/Users/dswork/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v6.7.0
20 error npm  v3.10.8
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error apicalltestapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the apicalltestapp@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the apicalltestapp package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     react-scripts start
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs apicalltestapp
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls apicalltestapp
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: seems like a problem in package.json script, could you post you package.json

Comment: Did you try running `npm i cross-spawn`?

Comment: delete folder `node_modules` and then try to start it again. sometime its happens to in order to restart.

Comment: @ItsGreg thanks, just tried it, still the same error.

Comment: @Veer this worked, thanks. however, why was this? Is there any explanation you might be aware of?

Comment: As of i know if you not shutdown npm manually then there are some files left as it is, which are created at run time and need to be deleted on shutdown process. so when you stat npm it check those file already exist and interrupt startup process. 
So as solution if you are not able to restart npm then delete deployment folder it self and npm create fresh copy of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see you lost `cross-spawn`

1. Check your package.json/npm-shrinkwrap.json has `cross-spawn` dependency. If you have not, then run `npm i --save cross-spawn`
2. If you have, then remove folder `node_modules`.
3. Run `npm install`

It will fix.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps,

1. create a new text file in project folder with the name .env
2. add **SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true**

This will simply ignore the error and let you start with React :)